# Using Rxjs with Node I/O operations

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs5

I am trying to use `Rxjs` with a small Node program that will do some I/O operations. Void operations (such as `writeFile`) have been done as Observables without any emitted values. It can be represented in a marble diagram as:

```
writeFile (success) ---------|
writeFile (error)   ---------X
```

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
removeDir    -------|
writeFiles          -------|
transformFiles             -------|
```

To accomplish these operations in the correct order, I have code that looks something like this:

```
// helpers.ts
import { Observable } from '@reactivex/rxjs';
export function removeDir(dir: string): Observable<void> { ... }
export function writeFiles(fromDir: string, toDir: string): Observable<void> { ... }
export function transformFiles(dir: string): Observable<void> { ... }

// main.ts
import { Observable } from '@reactivex/rxjs';
import { removeDir, writeFiles, transformFiles } from './helpers';

const filesReady = removeDir('output')
  .concat(Observable.defer(() => writeFiles('input', 'output')))
  .concat(Observable.defer(() => transformFiles('output')));

filesReady.subscribe({
  error(err) {
    // Something went wrong!
  }
  complete() {
    // Do something when files are ready
  }
})
```

This example is a bit simplified, but I run into issues in places where I want to compose Observables together. Many `Rxjs` operators does not work well with only complete events.

Is there a better way to compose `Rxjs` with I/O events?
I find some concepts around `Rxjs` confusing, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What don't you like about your current solution? What exact problems did you have with what operators?

Comment: @SergeySokolov  I wanted to compose the above observable with other value producing ones, but I tried using `switchMap()`. But I realize now that I could just use `concat()` or `merge()` instead. I think the process of writing this question already helped me understand it a bit better. Almost all examples of `Rxjs` show diagrams with values transformed by operators. The complete event is not as well documented.

Comment: I see. Indeed writing a question helps a lot. Btw, have you thought about streams returning some value as a signal of completion, instead of purely complete events?

Comment: I thought of it, but I could not decide what seemed like a good idea. All I could think of was arbitrary values like `'done'` or `true`. In the case of `fs.writeFile()`, I thought of returning the path to the file, but it seems a bit weird when Node does not return any value at all when the operation succeeds.